# vs15 profiling shows only app name

Tags: visual-studio, profiling

I'm new in visual studio, and use before only codeblocks with gcc-mingw.
The problem is: when i try to profile my application, i want to see list of functions but i get application name instead :
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrrmJ.png)

how fix it ?

---

linker command line :

/OUT:"{projects}\bin_vs14\Debug\NovaEngine.exe" /MANIFEST /PROFILE /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"{projects}\bin_vs14\Debug\NovaEngine.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE {manylibs} /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"{projects}\bin_vs14\Debug\NovaEngine.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"{projects}\bin_vs14\obj\Debug\NovaEngine.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module names are shown instead of function names if symbols cannot be resolved e.g. due to missing or out-of-date pdbs. Please ensure that you have up-to-date pdbs e.g. by running your app under debugger.

Also from your screenshot I suppose you have VS 2015 RTM, but not Update 1. Please try to upgrade to VS 2015 Update 1. It has a number of fixes in profiler related to symbol resolution.

Comment: Hm, yes Update 1 fix this and now prof works fine, thank you.